# Passing the current Item to a function

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, repeater

I have a Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterCategorie">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#((isBlocked()) ? "true" : "false") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

where I call a function on the .cs. I'd like to pass the current item (I mean, the current item iterate in the list of the datasource) to that function. How can I do it without passing the reference through the `isBlocked` function?

Comment: Why are you doing that as part of the Repeater?  Why not do this processing prior to displaying on the page?

Comment: Because are property not inside the Object that I iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterCategorie"
    OnItemDataBound="RepeaterCategorie_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Id="lblBool"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**CS**

```
protected void RepeaterCategorie_ItemDataBound(
    object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
        var lblBool = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblBool");
        lblBool.Text = isBlocked(sender, e) ? "true" : "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said, `without passing the reference through the isBlocked function`

Comment: @markzzz: sorry, missed that part as make little sense ;) Could you explain a little why you're trying to do this. It's not only curiosity, it might help me to provide a solution.

Comment: Such as using `object sender, EventArgs e` on functions on .cs: it should understand who call that function and pass the object!

Comment: @markzzz: Use [itemdatabound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event. It's the closer you can get I'd say.

Comment: @markzzz: updated answer. Passed `sender` and `e` to `isBlocked` but I'm not 100% if this what you're looking for as your motivation still hidden for me.

Comment: No. In fact I need to call `isBlocked()` in many part of code, inside the Repeater.